# Persist Grails Domains *ONLY* after Relationship built

Tags: grails, grails-orm, gorm-mongodb

I'm wondering if its possible to create a grails domain object, but only have it persist on command as opposed as when we do operations on it.

To be more precise, this is what I have to do now:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(name:"asdf")
Bar bar = new Bar(name:"gzxj")
bar.save() // persist here 
foo.save() // persist here
foo.addToBars(bar) //  now I have to build the relationship
```

What I want:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(name:"asdf")
Bar bar = new Bar(name:"gzxj")
foo.addToBars(bar) //  just build the relationship
bar.save() // would be great to ignore this step
foo.save() // can I now atomically build both objects and create the relationships?
```

My impressions is that the latter would be far faster if there are many relationships to associate.  Am I really just wanting NoSQL here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you have your relationships set up, this is entirely possible.  It really has nothing to do with what database you have implemented.

**Parent class**

```
class Foo {
    String name

    static hasMany = [bars: Bar]
}
```

**Child class**

```
class Bar { 
    String name

    Foo foo //optional back reference       
    static belongsTo = Foo
}
```

**Execution**

```
Foo foo = new Foo(name: 'a')
Bar bar = new Bar(name: 'b')
foo.addToBars(bar)
foo.save()

//or even more terse

Foo foo = new Foo(name: 'c')
foo.addToBars(new Bar(name: 'd'))
foo.save()
```

The key is the `belongsTo` which defaults to a [`cascade`](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/cascade.html) of `all`.  This can be explicitly set as well:

```
class Foo {
    String name

    static hasMany = [bars: Bar]

    static mapping = {
        bars cascade: 'all'
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh . . yeah, I probably don't have the belongsTo built.   It will be awhile before I'm able to test it, but it makes sense.